# animation play is very slow

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a wind field and cloth animation set up created, but when I hit the play button the animation is so slow. I can hardly tell the animation going.
How to set this to real time? 
Blender 2.81

Answer (score 0):

Two things. 1) Your CPU is probably lagging because cloth simulations take up a lot of processing power. 2) A way to fix this would be to set the playback of the animation to *Frame-dropping*. You can do this by going to the "playback" tab in the lower left side of Blender, and setting that to *Frame-Dropping*.

Comment: I set to frame dropping but it's still slow